# tf.while_loop() in call() of custom layer in TensorFlow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to write a custom layer that applies a dense layer and then some specified functions to the output of that computation. I want to specify the functions that are applied to the individual outputs in a list, such that I can easily change them.

I'm trying to apply the functions inside a `tf.while_loop`, but I don't know how to access and write to the individual elements of `dense_output_nodes`.

`dense_output_nodes[i] = ...` doesn't work as it tells me that

> TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment

So I tried to `tf.unstack` before, which is the code below, but now when creating the layer with `hidden_1 = ArithmeticLayer(unit_types=['id', 'sin', 'cos'])(inputs)`, I get the error that

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Tensor

because apparently TensorFlow converts `i` from `tf.constant` to `tf.Tensor`.

By now, I'm really struggling to see ways I can fix this. Is there some way I can get this to work?
Or should I build the whole `ArithmeticLayer` as a combination of a Dense layer and a Lambda layer applying the custom functions?

```
class ArithmeticLayer(layers.Layer):
    # u = number of units
    
    def __init__(self, name=None, regularizer=None, unit_types=['id', 'sin', 'cos']):
        self.regularizer=regularizer
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.u = len(unit_types)
        self.u_types = unit_types

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.u),
                                 initializer='random_normal',
                                 regularizer=self.regularizer,
                                 trainable=True)
        self.b = self.add_weight(shape=(self.u,),
                                 initializer='random_normal',
                                 regularizer=self.regularizer,
                                 trainable=True)


    def call(self, inputs):
        # get the output nodes of the dense layer as a list
        dense_output_nodes = tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b
        dense_output_list = tf.unstack(dense_output_nodes, axis=1)
        
        # apply the function units
        i = tf.constant(0)
        def c(i):
            return tf.less(i, self.u)
        def b(i):
            dense_output_list[i] = tf.cond(self.u_types[i] == 'sin',
                                            lambda: tf.math.sin(dense_output_list[i]),
                                            lambda: dense_output_list[i]
                                           )
            dense_output_list[i] = tf.cond(self.u_types[i] == 'cos',
                                            lambda: tf.math.cos(dense_output_list[i]),
                                            lambda: dense_output_list[i]
                                           )
            return (tf.add(i, 1), )
        [i] = tf.while_loop(c, b, [i])
        
        final_output_nodes = tf.stack(dense_output_list, axis=1)
        return final_output_nodes
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Is this not a datastructure question ? You can use [TensorArray](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorArray) or another structure instead of a list. Please check if the example works.

Comment: The question is if you want to apply the functions to the rows or columns of `dense_output_nodes`

Comment: @AloneTogether I want to apply the same function to all elements in the same column, as I want to treat every sample the same

Comment: So it is working for you with `tf.map_fn` ?

Comment: Yes, but I had changed the structure to a Dense layer followed by a Lambda layer, in which I apply the custom functions.
Should I share my solution as an answer?

Comment: Yes, and it seems to be working. I'm trying to implement the algorithm from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.02995.pdf), and it produces similar results, so I think the training, especially automatic differentiation is working with `map_fn`.

Comment: Cool! Sounds like an interesting project. Added an option with `tf.while_loop`, since that was the original question and is probably more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update` should do the trick if you want to apply certain functions column-wise across samples in a batch. Here is an example working in eager execution and graph mode:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class ArithmeticLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    # u = number of units
    
    def __init__(self, name=None, regularizer=None, unit_types=['id', 'sin', 'cos']):
        self.regularizer=regularizer
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.u_types = tf.constant(unit_types)
        self.u_shape = tf.shape(self.u_types)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.u_shape[0]),
                                 initializer='random_normal',
                                 regularizer=self.regularizer,
                                 trainable=True)
        self.b = self.add_weight(shape=(self.u_shape[0],),
                                 initializer='random_normal',
                                 regularizer=self.regularizer,
                                 trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        dense_output_nodes = tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b
        d_shape = tf.shape(dense_output_nodes)
        i = tf.constant(0)
        c = lambda i, d: tf.less(i, self.u_shape[0])

        def b(i, d):
          d = tf.cond(unit_types[i] == 'sin', 
                lambda: tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(d, tf.stack([tf.range(d_shape[0]), tf.repeat([i], d_shape[0])], axis=1), tf.math.sin(d[:, i])), 
                lambda: d)
          d = tf.cond(unit_types[i] == 'cos', 
                lambda: tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(d, tf.stack([tf.range(d_shape[0]), tf.repeat([i], d_shape[0])], axis=1), tf.math.cos(d[:, i])), 
                lambda: d)
          return tf.add(i, 1), d
        _, dense_output_nodes = tf.while_loop(c, b, loop_vars=[i, dense_output_nodes])

        return dense_output_nodes
x = tf.random.normal((4, 3))
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((3,))
arithmetic = ArithmeticLayer()
outputs = arithmetic(inputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(x, tf.random.normal((4, 3)), batch_size=2)
```

```
2/2 [==============================] - 3s 11ms/step - loss: 1.4259
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fe50728c850>
```

Comment: This is probably the way to go. I'll go ahead and rewrite my code one more time, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Just experiment and see what works best for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use a different datastructure then try this.

```
import tensorflow as tf

i = tf.constant(0)
u_types = ["sin","cos"]
u_types_ta = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.string,size=1, dynamic_size=True,clear_after_read=False)
for i in range(0, len(u_types)):
    u_types_ta = u_types_ta.write(i, u_types[i])
u = len(u_types)

dense_output_list = [1.,2.]
dense_output_ta = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32,size=1, dynamic_size=True,clear_after_read=False)
for i in range(0, len(dense_output_list)):
    dense_output_ta = dense_output_ta.write(i, dense_output_list[i])

ta = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32,size=1, dynamic_size=True,clear_after_read=False)


def c(i,_):
    return tf.less(i, u)


def b(i,ta):
    ta.write(i, tf.cond(u_types_ta.read(i) == 'sin',
                                   lambda: tf.math.sin(dense_output_ta.read(i)),
                                   lambda: dense_output_ta.read(i)
                                   ))
    ta.write(i, tf.cond(u_types_ta.read(i) == 'cos',
                                   lambda: tf.math.cos(dense_output_ta.read(i)),
                                   lambda: dense_output_ta.read(i)
                                   ))
    return (tf.add(i, 1),ta)


i,_ = tf.while_loop(c, b, [i,ta])
print(ta.stack())
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I could get this to work now. Directly with your code, the output shape of `ta.stack()` is `(None,)` when I put it into the `call()` function, but I need `(None, u)`.
I found a solution though, using `tf.map_fn()` so I didn't need any while loop anymore.